# how to use string as variable name in JavaScript with const and let?

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to use a string as a variable name. But do not know how to do this. There are maybe many others way like `map`. But I want to know the similar way like this:

`var ibrahim = 100`

`console.log(window['ibrahim'])`

output: 100

[image: Example code]

In JavaScript, if we declare a variable with `var` then it will store in the global scope. For that, we can access that variable through the `windows` object.

This method only works for `var`.

**I want to know if is there any similar way to do this with `const` and `let`?**

Comment: No, this is specific for `var` (and implicit globals).

Comment: Use an object or `Map` to present only the particular variables that you want accessible via a string.

Comment: `var` will only store on `window` if it's used in the global scope. If it's used in another scope, the variable will be local to that scope.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way. You need to declare window properties using `var`.